# Java not loading .dylib and .jnilib

Tags: java, macos, native, dylib

So I am attempting a basic load.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
System.load("/Users/Aaroneiros/Desktop/morfeusz2plugin/libmorfeusz2.dylib");
System.load("/Users/Aaroneiros/Desktop/morfeusz2plugin/libjmorfeusz.jnilib");
```

if the second load is commented out then it succeeds. However, if it isn't commented out I get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception that `libmorfeusz2.dylib` is not loaded.

I also tried using `System.loadLibrary` with lib names "libmorfeusz2" and "libmorfeusz2.dylib".

My java.library.path is pretty standard /Users/.../Library/Java/Extendsions: /Network/Library/Java/Extensions: /usr/lib/java etc.
I put `libmorfeusz2.dylib` and `libjmorfeusz.jnilib` into both `.../Library/Java/Extension`s and `/usr/lib/java/`. They are also in the same directory as the script that I'm running. So to my understanding that should work. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Or what could be wrong?

Edit.
It does work if I add them manually to IntelliJ idea's project but long story short I'm making elasticsearch plugin and I sort of can't really add that in by hand.

Edit 2.
Using the otool as suggested by @Siguza:

```
otool -l /Users/Aaroneiros/Desktop/morfeusz2plugin/libmorfeusz2.dylib | fgrep -A5 LC_ID_DYLIB
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name @executable_path/libmorfeusz2.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
```

and

```
otool -l /Users/Aaroneiros/Desktop/morfeusz2plugin/libjmorfeusz.jnilib | fgrep -A5 LC_LOAD_DYLIB
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name libmorfeusz2.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
--
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 7.5.0
compatibility version 7.0.0
--
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
--
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 111.1.4
compatibility version 1.0.0
```

Comment: Can you post the output of running `otool -l /Users/Aaroneiros/Desktop/morfeusz2plugin/libmorfeusz2.dylib | fgrep -A5 LC_ID_DYLIB` and `otool -l /Users/Aaroneiros/Desktop/morfeusz2plugin/libjmorfeusz.jnilib | fgrep -A5 LC_LOAD_DYLIB`?

Comment: Added to the first post @Siguza

Comment: I don't have the time to test this right now, but I have a strong feeling the `LC_ID_DYLIB` of the first lib would need to be just `libmorfeusz2.dylib`.

Comment: Is this something I can change myself somehow? Or the providers of this libraries have to do that?